# how to implement token in android login

Tags: android, security, protocols, access-token

i really have doubt 
i have created an android app and i will store the user information in mysql database using php.

Till here i got everything like using hash to store password safely in database by using bcryt as in encrypted form.

ok but now for authentication like if now user will login there should be secure communication between database and my application.
i studied about oauth but it works without any signup(really don't know much)

so my simple doubt is how to make this connection secure
like using some tokens ? somebody told me about seeds(i guess he was talking about tokens only ).
 Token will be generated and then at server site it will be checked then only access will be granted .
but i don't exactly how to use all this at login step.

i just want to know if there is any way so that there will be a secure communication between my app and the sever (firstly , for login )
or simple login with php is enough
i don't think so it will be enough

tokens are not used for login purposes ?

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Looking for Oauth This Link Will Help You

Clear And Easy To Understand

https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php.git

Documentation

http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/